# .htaccess - how to use ErrorDocument 404 without 404 in header?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have some files in /templates/ . Suppose I get an request /templates/something.html. I want to check if the actual file /templates/something.html exists and print it. Otherwise I want my script /search_here.php to do some work and print special output.

I'm using the below in my htaccess file.  It works almost fine, the only problem is that in case search_here.php do the work I see a good output, but server sends 404 header (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found). How can I turn off this header (my  /search_here.php will print this header in case of need)?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}     !/templates/

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /search_here.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `/search_here.php` as 404 handler.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule !^templates/ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ search_here.php [L]
```